# Microsoft Office or Visual Basic for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-office, visual-basic

Does anyone know if there is a way to use Microsoft Office or Visual Basic in Ubuntu?

Comment: There are alternatives you can use. Open Office and Mono coupled with a vb > c# converter

Comment: By saying "Visual Basic", are you referring to VBA?

Comment: If it's resolved, accept one of the answers, or if none helped, write your own and accept it.

Comment: @cocolover This article should be helpful http://nerdsmagazine.com/free-best-office-suite-for-linux/

Answer (score 8):

To run Windows applications on Linux, you can try wine (to install it, go to a command prompt and type `sudo apt-get install wine` or use the Sofware Center).

If you want an alternative, try OpenOffice, which is preinstalled on Ubuntu.

Comment: In the future, [LibreOffice](http://www.documentfoundation.org/download/) would be recommended instead of OpenOffice.

Comment: No more answers, please. This problem was resolved for 2 hours, i just didnt realize i could edit the title until now. (I'm a new user.)

Comment: @cocolover76, mark an answer as accepted so that people will know that a solution has been found. If you found one of your own solutions, you can add an answer to your own question and mark that as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Basic the closest equivalent (although not exact replacement) is [Gambas](http://gambas.sourceforge.net/en/main.html). Or just bite the bullet and learn Python with PyGTK.

Answer (score 0):

Libre Office can be used as an alternative for Microsoft Office and Gambas is a good alternative for Visual Basic. Both these soft-wares can be installed through Ubuntu Software Centre.